# QML: onDragStarted / finished not called even though the drag property is active

Tags: drag-and-drop, qml, draggable, qt-quick

In the following example I would expect that `onDragStarted` / `onDragFinished` are called when one rectangle is dragged. However only `drag.onActiveChanged` (of the mouseArea) and `Drag.onActiveChanged` (of the rectangle are called). I get the expected output when setting `Drag.dragType` to `Drag.Automatic` but then I don't see the rectangle anymore. I am using Qt 5.5 on a Mac (El Capitan).

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
  visible: true

  width: 100
  height: 200

  ListModel {
    id: testModel
    ListElement { name: "red";   value: "#f00" }
    ListElement { name: "green"; value: "#0f0" }
    ListElement { name: "blue";  value: "#00f" }
  }

  Component {
    id: rect
    Rectangle {

      Drag.active: mouseArea.drag.active
      Drag.hotSpot.x: width / 2
      Drag.hotSpot.y: height / 2
      //Drag.dragType: Drag.Automatic

      Drag.onActiveChanged: {
        console.log("Active changed..")
      }

      Drag.onDragStarted: {
        console.log("Drag started..")
      }

      Drag.onDragFinished: {
        console.log("Drag finished!")
      }

      MouseArea {
        id: mouseArea

        anchors.fill: parent
        hoverEnabled: true
        drag.target: parent

        drag.onActiveChanged: {
          console.log("Drag prop became active..")
        }

        onClicked: {
          colorButtonClicked(buttonName, buttonColor);
        }
      }

      width: 80
      height: 20
      radius: 6
      color: model.value
    }
  }

  Column {
    spacing: 3
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    Repeater {
      model: testModel
      delegate: rect
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Coundn't test it on my Mac but it works fine on my Win7 machine. Smells like a Mac implementation bug.

Comment: Confirmed here – El Capitain, Qt 5.5.1 – onDragStarted / onDragFinished are not called

Answer (score 6):

I was puzzled about the same problem based on my assumptions from the signal names, but a look at the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-drag.html#dragStarted-signal) showed that the signals will only work when using `Drag.Automatic` or explicitly calling `startDrag`.

> ### dragStarted()
>
> This signal is emitted when a drag is started with the startDrag() method or when it is started automatically using the dragType property.
>
> ### dragFinished(DropAction action)
>
> This signal is emitted when a drag finishes and the drag was started with the startDrag() method or started automatically using the dragType property.

The other issue seen when using `Drag.Automatic` appears to be fixed in Qt 5.6.1

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have to upgrade Qt on my Macbook and test it again at some point.